# Inconsistent result in SharedPreferences.getAll between android version

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

For the sake of this question, my `preference.xml` contains 3 items:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="300"
    android:key="edittext"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:summary="foo"
    android:title="bar" />

<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="switch"
    android:title="A switch" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:title="A checkbox" />
```

The setting activity:

```
class SettingsActivity : PreferenceActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragment()).commit()
    }
    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment(),
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        fun drawPreference() {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference)
            val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity)
            val prefCount = sharedPref.all.size

            }
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            drawPreference()
        }
}
```

The code is in `kotlin` and the line `sharedPref.all` is translated to java as `sharedPref.getAll()`

I find inconsistent result in this method call.

On my samsung galaxy S7 edge, android 7.0
`sharedPref.getAll()` returns `3` regardless of the stage of the switch and checkbox

On my samsung GT-S7572, android 4.1.2
`sharedPref.getAll()`

- returns `1` when the both switch and checkbox is in off state,
- returns `2` when either one of the switch and checkbox is in off state,
- returns `3` when both of the switch and checkbox is in on state

Anyone encountered the same issue?

Is it expected behaviour?

Or is it an issue of android version?

Or is it an issue of the phone?